# Prob. 3, Sec. 4.2 in Erwin Kreyszig's Functional Analysis: How to show that $\lim\sup$ is sublinear?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let's consider the real space $\ell^\infty$ of all bounded sequences of real numbers. Let $p \colon \ell^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$$p(x) \colon= \lim\sup_{n \to \infty} \xi_n \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \colon= (\xi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in \ell^\infty. $$
Then how to show that $p$ is sublinear?

That is, how to show that
$$p(x+y) \leq p(x) + p(y) \ \mbox{ for all  } \ x, y \in \ell^\infty,$$
and
$$p(\alpha x) = \alpha p(x) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x\in \ell^\infty \ \mbox{  and for all } \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \ \mbox{ such that } \ \alpha > 0?$$

Comment: Are you comfortable with the definition 
$$
\limsup \xi_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} \xi_m
$$
or is there some other definition that you prefer?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, this definition I've seen in Bartle and Sherbert, but I'm still unable to show this to be equivalent to the subsequential-limit-definition given by Rudin, or to the $\epsilon$-definition given by Tom M. Apostol. Which texts have you studied for your calculus and mathematical analysis courses?

Comment: I've studied Rudin; I think there's a problem in there where you show the equivalence of the definitions

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = (\xi_n)$ and $y = (\omega_n)$.  We note that
$$
p(x + y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} (\xi_m + \omega_m)
\leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sup_{m \geq n}\xi_m + \sup_{m \geq n}\omega_m\right)
= p(x) + p(y)
$$
To further expand on the inequality: we note that $A \subset B \implies \sup A \leq \sup B$.  This allows us to state that
$$
\begin{align} 
\sup_{m \geq n} (\xi_m + \omega_m) &= 
\sup\{\xi_m + \omega_m : m \geq n\} \\ 
&= \sup\{\xi_m + \omega_{m'} : m = m', m \geq n\} \\ 
& \leq \sup\{\xi_m + \omega_{m'} : m\geq n, m' \geq n\} \\ 
& = \sup\{\xi_m: m \geq n\} + \sup\{\omega_m: m \geq n\}
\end{align}
$$

---

Second part:
$$
p(\alpha x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} \alpha \xi_m = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha \sup_{m \geq n} \xi_m = 
\alpha \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} \xi_m = 
\alpha \,p(x)
$$

Comment: how do we obtain the second relation, the one involving a positive scalar?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud that one is easy; you just have to move the $\alpha$ out of the sup, and then out of the limit.  Both steps can be justified without much difficulty